# R: loop or filter over the dataframe and stop when specific condition is met

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, filter, filtering

**UPDATE:**

I have a dataframe df, which looks like this and it is chronological ordered by years.

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 990 | 4 |
| 990 | 2 |
| 990 | 4 |

**First Output I want to have is:**

***Per id the status should alsways start with 2, so if it starts with 4 it should be delted from the df***
I want to use a loop to filter over the id and that it stops, when per the number 4 occurs the first time per id:

so I want that it looks like this at the end:

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 990 | 2 |
| 990 | 4 |

**and the second output I want to have:**
It should stop with 4, no matter how often it occurs in the original dataset. After 4 nothing else should come.

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 2 |
| 601 | 4 |
| 990 | 2 |
| 990 | 4 |

I do not know how to do it? Maybe there is also a way with filtering?
I would really apreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you can use {dplyr} to get the first 4 rows of each `id`:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(id) %>% slice_head(n = 4)
```

How are your two questions different? Try adding some data that we can run and illustrate if the above is insufficient.

Comment: Hello, I try to filter the id in that way that it stops, when 1) the first 4 is occured in status and 2) the last 4 is occured in status. In both cases it should stop with the value 4. Hope it helps